# $T : V → \mathbb{R}^2$ which assigns to every $f(x)$ the pair of its values at $x = −1$ and $x = 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the space of all polynomials $f(x)$ of degree $\le 2$. Consider a linear map
$T : V → \mathbb{R}^2$ which assigns to every $f(x)$ the pair of its values at $x = −1$ and $x = 1$.

For instance, $T(x^2) = (1,1)$.

I  cannot understand the given information:

> "$T : V → \mathbb{R}^2$ which assigns to every $f(x)$ the pair of its
>   values at $x = −1$ and $x = 1$."

Is it means that $T(f)=\left(f(1),f(-1)\right)$? I get quite confused.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the idea.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$The expression "$T:V \to \Reals^{2}$", read "$T$ from $V$ to $\Reals^{2}$" (or perhaps "$T$ maps $V$ to $\Reals^{2}$", depending on the surrounding English grammar) signifies that $T$ is a mapping that accepts elements of $V$ as inputs and returns elements of $\Reals^{2}$ as outputs.

Conceptually, this is just like a function $f:\Reals \to \Reals$ in calculus; to each real number $x$ that is "input" to $f$, the function $f$ returns a unique "output" $y = f(x)$.

Here the inputs are not numbers, but *quadratic polynomials* $f$, defined by expressions $f(x) = ax^{2} + bx + c$, and the outputs are *ordered pairs of real numbers*, $T(f) = \bigl(f(-1), f(1)\bigr)$.

In answering the question to which this definition is attached, it will probably help to evaluate $f(\pm1)$ in terms of the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$.

---

In case a worked example helps make things more concrete, suppose instead $T(f) = \bigl(f(0), f(2)\bigr)$. If $f(x) = ax^{2} + bx + c$, then $f(0) = c$ (plug in $x = 0$) and $f(2) = 4a + 2b + c$ (plug in $x = 2$), so the mapping $T$ is given by
$$
T(f) = (c, 4a + 2b + c).
$$
(It's convenient, though not perfect mathematical grammar, to write $T(ax^{2} + bx + c) = (c, 4a + 2b + c)$.)

Even more particularly, if $f_{0}(x) = -x^{2} + 3x + 6$, then $f_{0}(0) = 6$ and $f_{0}(2) = -4 + 6 + 6 = 8$, so $T(f_{0}) = (6, 8)$, or (being a bit sloppy) $T(-x^{2} + 3x + 6) = (6, 8)$.

Comment: Note to posterity: This answered one previous incarnation of the question, but the question is now entirely different....